# Angular 9 / TypeScript Static Code Analyzers

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, code-analysis

If I use ESLint then is there any reason to also use tslint?  Or is ESLint mean to be a replacement?

Answer (score 5):

The [tslint homepage](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) seems [pretty clear](https://medium.com/palantir/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9):

> TSLint has been deprecated as of 2019. […] typescript-eslint is now your best option for linting TypeScript.

There is a published [roadmap](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534) for how to wind down tslint until December, 2019.

[typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/) is the future of listing for TypeScript.